# IdentityServer3 - Add custom form fields to FormPostResponse.html

Tags: identityserver3

We have set up IdentityServer for an angular app and all works fine when accessed internally. The reverse proxy that we use for external access expects few hidden form fields for all POST requests.

I have checked there are no options to add these fields directly. Are there any workarounds to add more fields to FormPostResponse.html?

We are using CustomViewService and Hybrid Flow.

Edited: (removed ang tag)
I am trying to add these in by amending the response in OWIN middleware to add the fields.

Anyone has had the same requirement before? If yes, please detail the work around.

Comment: Please add some code samples (html/js) and show us what you already tried. Perhaps this documentation is of any help for adding extra parameters to the POST request: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: Thanks @FrankvanWijk sorry the problem isnt angular. I tagged just because I am using angularjs implementation of IdentityServer3 UI. IdentityServer3 has an embedded html page that carries token values to be posted back to client. I was wondering if any one had the same requirement as mine i.e. addition of hidden fields to this POST action. Will edit the question to note my current approach to work around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can customize the form post response html as of 2.4 of IdentityServer3. Here's the post on the issue tracker that mentions how to do it: https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/issues/2124#issuecomment-172378110

You might need to derive from `DefaultViewService` and override `LoadHtmlTemplate` for the `"authorizeresponse"` view and inject your own form fields prior to the base class doing its normal work.

Comment: Thanks Brock. We are using CustomView now so I will explore if we can use `DefaultViewService` instead. 

Also I note the following point in your linked post -  **In the 3.0 time frame a more formal API will be added to the view service interface so people not using the DefaultViewService will also be able to replace it** and will look forward to this being implemented. Thanks!